# Can we test country/region condition of Remote Config by using vpn?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

I created parameter which returns true at Japan others false by using country/region condition.

Then I fetched the parameter on my app, but the parameter is not changed w/o vpn connection to United States.

Can we test country/region condition by using vpn?
How does country/region condition check geographical information?